# Checking the sum of a series

Tags: calculus

Can you verify if the following series has the indicated sum ?
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(8+8 i) \sqrt{2} \sec (\pi  k) \left(\sin \left(\sqrt[4]{-1} \pi  k\right)-\sinh \left(\sqrt[4]{-1} \pi  k\right)\right)}{\pi ^4 k^{11} \left(\cos \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  k\right)-\cosh \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  k\right)\right)}=\frac{1219 \pi ^7}{104781600}$$

Comment: What do you mean by $\sqrt[4]{-1}$ ? Is it $e^{i\tfrac{\pi}{4}}$ ?

Comment: When I see expressions like $\cos(a)-\cosh(a)$ in the denominator, I think at once to complex function theory. Do you know this domain ?

Comment: Yes Jean Marie it is so

Comment: this account  expire in two hour , i am tired to many inapropiate and offensive response ,here there are a lot of pepople want to help  but the most it is only interesting in make point i do not why , other time some body have  to appropiate of many formulas and others do not help really  . buy anyway

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "this account expires in 2 hours". Don't bother about people reacting like this or like that on this site (this is much more important on the international scene !). I have a question : where have you seen this series ? And how do you know that the answer should be this one ? It looks like very complex formulas found by Ramanujan. I could "check" it in an approximate manner but this has no value unless detecting some basic flaw...

Comment: Thanks Jean but I publish a lot of series it is alway the same vote to close or inapropiate commentary this series are mine but i do not if it  are correct need more esplanation at all

Comment: I am going to try with Matlab. Result in not too long time.

Comment: There is a problem in my simulation because I find all terms equal to 0 except the first one (for $k=1$). I have replaced $\sec(\pi k)$ by $(-1)^k$ but here is not the problem.

Comment: In fact, I have found my error, there is a striking coincidence !

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Comment: I have had a look at the answers that were given to you  for other formulas. It is true that sometimes some people are criticizing you. And I understand it may be hard. But maybe, it is simply because they don't understand the way you think. You should provide hopefully some details about the way you arrived at these **astonishing** formulas (for some of them) i.e., the mental process that has been yours.... One thing is sure : don't stop there. We much need people like you !

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I should notice is that, if $a_k$ is given by 
$$a_k=\frac{(8+8 i) \sqrt{2} \sec (\pi  k) \left(\sin \left(\sqrt[4]{-1} \pi  k\right)-\sinh \left(\sqrt[4]{-1} \pi  k\right)\right)}{\pi ^4 k^{11} \left(\cos \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  k\right)-\cosh \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  k\right)\right)}$$ it can simplify as
$$a_k=(-1)^k\,\frac{16 \sqrt 2}{\pi^4}\frac 1 {k^{11}}\,\,\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \cosh \left(\frac{\pi 
   k}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \sinh
   \left(\frac{\pi  k}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\cos \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  k\right)-\cosh
   \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  k\right)}$$

The first term is  $\approx 3.513632183\times 10^{-2}$, the second     $\approx 9.307320089 \times 10^{-7}$ and the other are smaller and smaller.

Computing the value of each of the $a_k$'s to $1000$ significant figures and adding them up, the following partial sums are obtained (only $100$ significant figures are reported below)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \sum_{k=1}^p a_k \\
 10 &
   0.035137251622994013551070350858007249920081542835700944612937703235819722897168
   47209413823775955918232 \\
 20 &
   0.035137251622994013551041573282473434746885691144183194559092680440045387621277
   32758321227982320205142 \\
 30 &
   0.035137251622994013551041573282473439927500154501819388562624851624070873512670
   48957059396054055896089 \\
 40 &
   0.035137251622994013551041573282473439927500154486905099352207661384811333906152
   10075886966261805899505 \\
 50 &
   0.035137251622994013551041573282473439927500154486905099352342509049444477861615
   99253343083502801844077 \\
 60 &
   0.035137251622994013551041573282473439927500154486905099352342509049442279555102
   30653278563803998753290 \\
 70 &
   0.035137251622994013551041573282473439927500154486905099352342509049442279555102
   35463921121510938585220 \\
 80 &
   0.035137251622994013551041573282473439927500154486905099352342509049442279555102
   35463921121406379289749 
\end{array}
\right)$$ and this is "excatly" the value of $\frac{1219\, \pi ^7}{104781600}$ for $100$ significant figures.

Pushing the summation to $p=1000$, the difference between lhs and rhs is $6.5 \times 10^{-1000}$.

Comment: Bonsoir, Claude ! This OP said yesterday evening that "his account expires in 2 hours" (see above) ; indeed, clicking now on his pseudo doesn't give any longer access to his numerous questions of "Ramanujan type" ...

Comment: @JeanMarie. I did not notice that point ! Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a numerical "checking" with a Matlab program that the formula is very **likely** to be valid. The amazing fact is the superconvergence of this series : only five terms are needed to get a 15 decimals coincidence.

Of course, one should use a multiprecision software... And there will remain some doubt until a "true" proof is found...

> ```
> clear all;
> format long
> i=complex(0,1);
> s2=sqrt(2);r=(1+i)/s2;
> S=0;
> for k=1:5
>    u=r*pi*k;
>    v=s2*pi*k; 
>    S=S+((-1)^k)*(sin(u)-sinh(u))/((k^(11))*(cos(v)-cosh(v)));
> end;
> r1=16*r*S/(pi^4)
> r2=1219*(pi^7)/104781600
> %both r1 and r2 are equal to 0.035137251622994
> ```